# Azure Keyvault to retrieve secure value

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

```
const string secretName = "MyConnectionString";
var kvUri = "https://{vaultname}.vault.azure.net/{}";

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secret.Value.Value}'.");
```

I get an error:

> http 404 - File or directory not found.
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Check if the resource is available on portal?

Comment: What are the curly braces for in the url?

Answer (score 0):

> http 404 - File or > directory not found.
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

The above error **404 - File or directory not found** indicates that the resource you are trying to access might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please make sure that you have provided the correct values for the variables `secretName` and `kvUri`.

In my environment, I passed the parameters with the correct vault name and secret name to retrieve the secret value.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        string vaultName = "<Your-keyvault-name>";
        string secretName = "MyConnectionString";
        var kvUri = $"https://{vaultName}.vault.azure.net/";
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Your secret is '{secret.Value.Value}'.");
    }
}
```

The above code is used to retrieve a secret from an Azure Key Vault. It creates a `SecretClient` object that is authenticated using the `DefaultAzureCredential` and the URI of the Azure Key Vault. The `GetSecret` method is then used to retrieve the secret with the specified name from the Azure Key Vault.

**Output:**

```
Your secret is 'Hellomyworld'.
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Quickstart - Azure Key Vault secrets client library for .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net?tabs=azure-cli#sample-code)